# C3P0 Connection Pool

Tags: mysql, hibernate, conexão

Tenho as seguintes propriedades no meu ***Hibernate*** XML para ***Connection Pool*** retirado da internet:

```
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="4"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="4"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
```

Porém não tenho conhecimento de como configurar tais propriedades se baseando nas configurações do meu banco.

***O que devo levar em consideração para configurar cada uma das propriedades?***