# User has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 4)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Estou com um problema referente as conexões abertas no banco, onde está ocorrendo erro caso a aplicação tente criar mais conexões que o limite. Supondo que a aplicação cria e fecha as conexões por cada interação no banco (insert/update/select), **como fazer com que a aplicação "espere" por uma nova conexão?** Estou usando hibernate + java.

```
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("model");
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();

        manager.getTransaction().begin();    
        manager.persist(produto);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();  

        manager.close();
        factory.close();
```

> Edit

Dei uma olhada sobre `SessionFactory`, configurei a aplicação para usar o Connection Pool `hibernate.cfg.xml` , porém ainda ocorre o erro.

#### **HibernateUtils.java**

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

#### Aqui o Método de gravar

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(produto);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

#### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <!-- Pool de conexão -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">4</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

    <!-- entidade mapeada -->
    <mapping class="br.com.sales.model.ProdutosVO" />
```

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: http://www.devmedia.com.br/connection-pool/5869

Comment: @Ricardo Tenho configurado, porém não surgiu efeitos. Tenho uma pergunta pendente sobre isso aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130234/c3p0-connection-pool

Comment: Cara, creio que a solução seja a criança de uma Classe Banco Singleton, assim o Banco só tem uma instância no programa todo e não se permite criar mais de uma conexão com o banco. [Aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-singleton-em-java/26392) você encontra mais sobre isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Fica aqui a resposta para todos que estiverem com o mesmo problema referente a configuração do c3p0.

O erro foi solucionado apenas definindo o `hibernate.connection.provider_class` no `xml`. Até onde eu li, sem definir o provider, o c3p0 não é executado.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

#### Obrigatóriamente ter essas 3 libs em seu `classhPath`

```
c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar
hibernate-c3p0-4.2.4.Final.jar
mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar
```

***Outro problema encontrado também*** foi para as conexões ociosas que ficam no `connection pool`, onde caso a aplicação tente executar uma operação usando tais conexões, ocorre erro `Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.` Para solução, foi alterado o tempo que a aplicação fica testando as conexões ativas antes do `timeout`.

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
// Test_period tem de ser um numero menor que o timeout.
// Neste caso, a aplicação fica testando as conexões a cada 100s
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
```

**Obs:** também deve-se ter o cuidado de fechar as session depois de cada operação.

**Exemplo:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Empresa> getEmpresasConnectionPool() throws Exception{
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<Empresa> lista = session.createQuery("select t from Empresa as t ORDER BY id ASC").list();
        return lista;       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(Validation.getCause(e));
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```